# What does 低喝了一声 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 低喝了一声

I could not see how 喝 here means drink, so I tried to look further in my dictionary and it says:

> The same as 嗬, which is an onomatopoeia

Which kind of makes sense since I also found a similar expression: 哼了一声.

However the dictionary seems to give it a tone of surprise, but in that case what does it mean together with 低? Maybe I could translate the sentence as:

> he made a small oh

Comment: 低声，low voice, whisper, mutter, iciba:喝 [hè]

（大声喊叫） shout loudly

give a loud shout

大喝一声

shout a question to

喝问.
声：verbal measure word,user suggestion: gave a low shout

Comment: @user6065 interesting, at the beginning I also thought about "shout", however it was difficult to imagine what is a small shout, so I began thinking about other hypothesis.anyway It makes sense now, thank you

Comment: @Lex I think you're on the right track, baidu has many results for 低喝一声 which in context would mean "to cry out softly" as if you were dismayed or surprised but because you were in a dangerous situation you had to control your volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

低喝 here may be a shout but not aloud. 喝 is not only drink, but also shout. 低 here is about the voice

Answer (score 2):

(He/She) shouted in a low voice...